# Return warning in addition to reply in mvc kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I created kendo grid in view which gets its data from a controller method. If there are no errors the rows are returned to view. If there is an error the error is returned using event onError.
In controller:

```
        public ActionResult LoadgridData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string arg)
    {
        var result = SomeApiCall();

        if (result.Count == 0)
        {
            return this.Json(new DataSourceResult
            {
                Errors = "Some error occured"
            });
        }

        //TODO: send warning if result.Count > 1000

        return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This method LoadgridData is used in kendo grid read.Action

I want to send back a warning from this method when data size is more than a threshold.
Does anyone know how I can do it

Comment: Why don't you just check it on the front-end if the length of the results is greater than 1,000?

Comment: I am trying to cut back memory consumed on server as well as client. If I do it in front end how different would it be than just trimming the reply in the back end? Also, is there a good way to do it in the front end? I am new to mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error right there in that *TODO* throwing an `Exception` or returning a `BadRequest()`.

Then in your [DataSource `error` event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/error) you can handle it and show a message.

Example:

```
public ActionResult LoadgridData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string arg)
{
    var result = SomeApiCall();

    if (result.Count == 0)
    {
        return this.Json(new DataSourceResult
        {
            Errors = "Some error occured"
        });
    }
    else if (result.Count >= 1000)
    {
        // Option #1
        throw new Exception("Too many records");

        // Option #2
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

DataSource:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    data: {
        url: ...
        error: () => {
            window.alert('Too many records');
        }
```

UPDATE:

To show both data and error, you can customize the ajax request, so you will be able to intercept the result before its displayed. Then you return both error and data in the same result:

```
kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(result) {
          // Show message to user
          window.alert(result.error);

          // Print data to grid
          options.success(result.data);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/icUzovin)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I throw the error I won't be able to access the rows in the grid. I want to show maximum allowed rows in the grid, and show a message on UI that says Too many records were found but showing first 1000 rows

Comment: I realized if I throw error then I can't show data in the grid. And vice versa.

Comment: @MaheshMhatre check my update

Comment: thanks for the update. I will try this :)